# C# - Effect of returning byte array of memory stream just before disposing stream?

Tags: c#, arrays, stream, dispose, memorystream

I am using a memory stream like this:

```
public static byte[] myMethod()
{
    using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
       //some processing here.
       return stream.toArray();
    }
}
```

I am assigning the returned byte array in the caller method like this:

```
public static void callerMethod()
{
    byte[] myData = myMethod();
   //Some processing on data array here
}
```

Is the returned byte array passed by reference or by value? If the returned array is by reference does that mean at any time I may have **myData** in the **callerMethod** array to be ***null*** at any time while I am still processing the data?

Comment: How should the byte array change 'while you are still processing'? If it isn't assigned yet, how can it change?

Comment: You asking if the array will be null after the stream is disposed? That won't happen.

Comment: It is assigned by calling myMethod(), I guess It will be changed if the byte array is returned by reference, because the memory stream object now will be a subject for GC any time after execution exits using block in the called method?

Comment: Thanks @Rinecamo, yeah that exactly what I am asking for.

Comment: ToArray() returns and a new array filled with the stream data, so you can dispose the stream safely without loosing your data array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the returned byte array passed by reference or by value?

An array is an instance of an `Array` class, so it is always a reference and no value. `ToArray` reads the values from the stream and stores them in a newly instantiated array object.

> does that mean at any time I may have ... null

No. As explained above, you return a new array instance containing the values read from the stream. There is no chance that your local variable `myData` will be set to `null` again while you work with it.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a reference, but you data will be store somewhere in your memory.
So When "myMethod" will return, stream will be closed but your array will still contain the data.
The only way you array could be null would be that your stream doesn't contain any data.